# Where can I invite testers to test my apps?

Tags: discussion, scope

I code four new apps for Android (three games and one business community app). I want to invite testers and get feedback from users. Can I do that here, or do you know where I can invite users to test my apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This site is about solving issues users have with their Android devices – not about seeking staff for develpoment, testing etc. So: **No,** you can't use this site to invite testers.

As for where to do that: I'm not aware of any SE site permitting that. Some forum might be a good place; see [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](/q/371/16575)